# Regex rich the limit?

Tags: regex, zend-framework

I have some code to routing my url (every user has is own addres like: domain.com/username)
The problem is I get some errors because my regex is too large(?)

How can I solve this?

```
        $user_nick=user::getAllUserNick();//this return string like: username1|username2 etc.
        $user_url_firstpage = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
                '('.$user_nick.'+)', 
                array('controller' => 'ads', 'action' => 'category', 'page' => 1), array(1 => 'nick', 2 => 'page'), '%s/'
        );
```

error log:

```
[28-Sep-2020 07:18:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset 83837 in D:\netbeans-projects\mysite\library\Zend\Controller\Router\Route\Regex.php on line 83
```

Comment: What's error message?  Have you tried to debug your programme?

Comment: Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).